# How to remap C-c?

Tags: emacs, keymapping

Given that there are so many major modes which define their own maps for this prefix (e.g. latex, org, term), is there a safe way to move these maps somewhere else, and always have the `C-c` key free?

I'm hoping there's a convenient way, because I noticed ErgoEmacs does exactly this.

Comment: All "nice" modes should leave `C-c <some-character>` free. I've seen ergoemacs use these keys

Comment: Nice minor modes, yes. But there are plenty of major modes which use the C-c prefix (and that includes built-in ones). I want to know how to remap it so I can use C-c for something else.

Comment: Really? What major modes use C-c some-letter? A simple way is to clobber the keybinding in a hook

Comment: @jozefg off the top of my head: Org and auctex are the most relevant to me, but I'm sure there are others.

Comment: The reserved sequences are `C-c <letter>` for lower- and upper case letters (i.e. `[a-zA-Z]`), and the function keys `F5` to `F9`. Other `C-c` bindings are reserved for other purposes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418561/avoiding-overlapped-keybindings-in-emacs/16419890#16419890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, there no easy way, unless you dive deep into emacs innards and create ways to remap every mode's keys on load. (I think Matthew Fidler is actually working on this)

ergoemacs-mode does not remap the C-c. It turns on cua-mode, but cua-mode doesn't remap C-c neither, it just create several clever ways so that key can be used for multiple purposes (e.g. by the speed you press the key, or whether there's a text selection, etc.). All C-c * keys are still there.

see discussion on this same question here
https://plus.google.com/103652929131043355278/posts/Nb4xn4gDB6p

Comment: See also what the Elisp manual says: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html#Key-Binding-Conventions