# Key bindings do not work in emacs scheme mode

Tags: emacs, emacs24, mit-scheme

I am following the guide [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Interrupting.html) for emacs lisp interface.

`C-c q` is supposed to quit scheme mode. However this shows `C-c q is undefined` error. Typing `(exit)` on REPL works fine. Why is this key not bound in my emacs?

Comment: `C-c q` is [reserved for users](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16419890/324105). Any mode binding that sequence is in error.

Comment: @phils So the information in the manual is incorrect?

Comment: Well it sounds as if either the manual is incorrect, or the library is not following the key conventions (which should be considered a bug). As you say that binding doesn't do what the manual said it would, I would assume the manual is incorrect.

Comment: I don't actually see `C-c q` listed in the page you linked to, btw. You should also try `C-h m` from the buffer in question, as it's very common for a mode's help text to include its key bindings.

Comment: +1 to `C-h m`.  If that does not show enough key bindings, try `C-h b`, which lists all current bindings.  Look for the command name you expect should do what you're looking for.

Comment: @phils `"I don't actually see C-c q listed in the page you linked to"` Sorry linked to wrong page of manual. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see "Note that in any given implementation, only a subset of the following keys is available", but more importantly I don't believe that documentation is talking about Emacs bindings.

My impression is that those are the bindings recognised by the REPL if you were to run it *outside* of Emacs.

Inside Emacs you *possibly* need a prefix to say "send the next sequence to the REPL". e.g. in Emacs' term you have to type `C-c C-c` instead of just `C-c` to send an interrupt to the terminal. However as it's not listed in the [other page](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-user/GNU-Emacs-Interface.html) which listed interrupts in Emacs, I *suspect* there actually isn't an equivalent binding. Or at least not by default.

Comment: You're right. `C-c q` is recognized in REPL if I run that in bash. Previously I had not seen `C-c` style key bindings being used in any other software so I assumed the guide was talking about emacs.